# Is there a way to save a GPU Frame Capture from Xcode?

Tags: xcode

I have two different projects/implementations for the same app (same bundle identifier). I want to take two GPU Frame Captures, one from each project, on the same device, and compare both.

I can't do that because in order to take the second I must stop the first. So is there a way to save the Frame Capture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

On top you should see a toolbar with the .gputrace.  You can right-click it and see its path.

[image]

Comment: And is there a way to compare both?

Answer (score -1):

Xcode has the standard way of using File > Export for that (which also compresses your GPU trace).
Also the GPU Trace Summary has a prominent Export button.